# How can i correctly inject dependency with @Autowired in the spring project without use getBean? Is it Possible?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, dependencies, code-injection

1 - I want to inject "loginService" with @Autowired without calling getBean, but is not working. It is null. Only work with getBean. 
I would appreciate some explanation.

SpringContext.xml

```
<!-- to activate annotations in beans already registered in the application context -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- scans packages to find and register beans within the application context -->
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.cpb.gsa" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myserver:1433;databaseName=" />
    <property name="username" value="" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

LoadPoolConnection - to load SpringContext ( i don´t know if this class needs be static )

```
public class LoadPoolConnection {

private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

static {

    applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("br/com/cpb/gsa/SpringContext.xml");

}

public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return applicationContext;
}
```

}

UserDAO

```
public interface UserDAO{

    public Usuario getAuthenticatedUser( String login );

}
```

UserDAOImpl

```
@Repository("userDAO")
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public Usuario getAuthenticatedUser(String login) {

        try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()){

            //... sample code, just for explanation ...
            Usuario user = new Usuario();
            user.setLogin("test");

            return user;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }
}
```

LoginService - Interface

```
public interface LoginService {
    public Usuario doLogin(Usuario user);   
}
```

LoginServiceImpl

```
@Service("loginService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4014652022146807624L;

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public Usuario doLogin(Usuario user){

        if ((user == null) ||              (JavaUtil.isNull(user.getLogin(),"").trim().length() == 0)){
            throw new RuntimeException(Constant.LOGIN_OR_PASSWORD_NOT_PROVIDED);
        }

        //UsuarioDAO dao = (UsuarioDAO)     applicationContext.getBean("usuarioDAO");   
        Usuario savedUser = userDAO.getAuthenticatedUser(user.getLogin());  

        if  ( (savedUser == null) || (!savedUser.getSenha().equals(user.getSenha())) ){
            throw new RuntimeException(Constant.INVALID_USER_OR_PASSWORD);
        }

        return user;
    }

}
```

In the follow class the loginService is null, even with @Autowired

```
public class TestLoginService {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private static LoginService loginService;

    private static void doLogin(){

        Usuario user = new Usuario();
        user.setLogin("weles");
        user.setSenha("test");

        //loginService = (LoginService) applicationContext.getBean("loginService");  //with this command works, but i would like don´t user this call.

        Usuario savedUser = loginService.doLogin(user);
        System.out.println(savedUser.getLogin());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        applicationContext = LoadPoolConnection.getApplicationContext();
        doLogin();

    }

}
```

In the future i would like to use Pool, thus i am using LoadPoolConnection, but i don´t know if this appoach is good.

I would appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove `static`. You cannot inject static fields. Next to that your `TestLoginService` will never get injected as it isn't a spring managed bean.

Answer (score 1):

Spring container injects the dependencies only when you a class is marked with `@Service` or `@Controller` (etc.. `stereotype` annotations look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/stereotype/package-summary.html)).
So you need to mark your TestLoginService with `@Service` in order to execute the field injection for `@Autowired` fields.

So you need to change your `TestLoginService` class as shown below:

```
@Service
public class TestLoginService {

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    private void doLogin(){

        Usuario user = new Usuario();
        user.setLogin("weles");
        user.setSenha("test");

        Usuario savedUser = loginService.doLogin(user);
        System.out.println(savedUser.getLogin());
    }
}
```

If you want to maintain `TestLoginService` class separately, then you definitely need `ApplicationLauncher`  class as shown below and then you need to get the `TestLoginService` bean object through spring `context`.

**ApplicationLauncher  class:**

```
public class ApplicationLauncher {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
             applicationContext = LoadPoolConnection.getApplicationContext();
             TestLoginService testLoginService = (TestLoginService)applicationContext.
                       getBean("testLoginService"); 
             testLoginService.doLogin();
     }
}
```

Comment: Your example won't compile (you access a non-static variable from a static method).

Answer (score 1):

If Spring is not creating your objects, it cannot inject the dependencies into them.

You need to get an instance of TestLoginService from the container - it will come properly initialised.

```
@Service
public class TestLoginService {
    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    private void doLogin(){
        Usuario user = new Usuario();
        user.setLogin("weles");
        user.setSenha("test");

        Usuario savedUser = loginService.doLogin(user);
        System.out.println(savedUser.getLogin());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         applicationContext = LoadPoolConnection.getApplicationContext();

         applicationContext.getBean(TestLoginService.class).doLogin();
    }
}
```